# Matrix multiplication with Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have a numerical analysis assignment and I need to find some coefficients by multiplying matrices. We were given an example in Mathcad, but now we have to do it in another programming language so I chose Python.

The problem is, that I get different results by multiplying matrices in respective environments. Here's the function in Python:

```
    from numpy import *
def matrica(C, n):
N = len(C) - 1
m = N - n
A = [[0] * (N + 1) for i in range(N+1)]
A[0][0] = 1
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    A[i][i] = 1
for j in range(1, m + 1):
    for i in range(0, N + 1):
        if i + j <= N:
            A[i+j][n+j] = A[i+j][n+j] - C[i]/2
        A[int(abs(i - j))][n+j] = A[int(abs(i - j))][n+j] - C[i]/2
M = matrix(A)
x = matrix([[x] for x in C])
return [float(y) for y in M.I * x]
```

As you can see I am using **numpy** library. This function is consistent with its analog in Mathcad until `return` statement, the part where matrices are multiplied, to be more specific. One more observation: this function returns correct matrix if `N = 1`.

Comment: Correct the indentation.  Use `import numpy as np`.  Show what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Sorry but your code is not clear as your indentation has not come over from your cut & paste. Also, it would be good if you gave us sample input & output with the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what your code do.  Could you explain a little more, like what math stuff you're actually computing.  But if you want a plain regular product and if you use a `numpy.matrix`, why don't you use the already written matrix product?

```
a = numpy.matrix(...)
b = numpy.matrix(...)
p = a * b #matrix product
```

Comment: You mean to do this: p = M.I * x and then return p? No, that does not help.

Comment: *What* are you trying to compute, what is your expected result and what is your actual result?  You just throw code at us and says "See?  There's a problem!"  How am I supposed to know what's wrong if I don't know what's right?

Comment: I said what is right, it is result in Mathcad. The problem is with multiplication itself.

Comment: I know python, not mathcad.  Is "result" a function you try to mimic?  A link to what you refer?  By the way, all you said is "We were given an example in Mathcad" and "I need to find some coefficients".  An example of *what*?  Coefficients of *what*?

Comment: An example of same function. Coefficients of chebyshev approximation used in calculation uf hyperbolic arcsine.

Comment: Result in Mathcad is matrix with wrong coefficients and result in python is matrix with bad coefficients.

Comment: Please edit you question and take 20 minutes (or your whole day if that's what it takes) to *explain* in much more detail all of that, giving links, like this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials and also describing in a *clear* way what you're trying to do (the math algorithm/formula), what you should have and what you actually have.  (what is the difference between "bad" coefficients and "wrong coefficient"???)

Comment: How do I delete question?

Comment: Below the tags, there are the questions links.  There is a `delete`, but you should use `edit` and change your question from there.